# print a character at end of line-Python

Tags: python

I'm spliting a tab separated log file and write it in to another file. For the agent (line.split('\t')[9]) I want to put double quotes("") for the beginning and end. Following is how I did it in two methods. But in the output file the end quote is printed at the beginning of next line. I tried different things but still didn’t get the expected result. Hope you understand my question?

```
#method 01
agent = '"'+(line.split('\t')[9])+'"'
#method 02
agent = ''.join(('"',line.split('\t')[9],'"'))

fo.write(ip + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + time +' ' + method + ' ' + status + ' ' + '0' + ' ' + referrer + ' ' + agent)
```

output

```
120.151.224.62 - - [26/Nov/2012:23:59:59 -0600] "GET /comworks/default.asp" 200 0 "" "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0)
"101.2.186.21 - - [27/Nov/2012:00:00:01 -0600] "GET /online/2/2/22002.aspx" 200 0 "https://www.example.com/online/2/2/22001.aspx" "Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/23.0.1271.64+Safari/537.11
"101.2.186.21 - - [27/Nov/2012:00:00:01 -0600] "GET /online/Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx" 200 0 "https://www.exsample.com/online/2/2/22002.aspx" "Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/23.0.1271.64+Safari/537.11
```

Expected output

```
120.151.224.62 - - [26/Nov/2012:23:59:59 -0600] "GET /comworks/default.asp" 200 0 "" "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0)"
101.2.186.21 - - [27/Nov/2012:00:00:01 -0600] "GET /online/2/2/22002.aspx" 200 0 "https://www.exsample.com/online/2/2/22001.aspx" "Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/23.0.1271.64+Safari/537.11"
101.2.186.21 - - [27/Nov/2012:00:00:01 -0600] "GET /online/Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx" 200 0 "https://www.exsample.com/online/2/2/22002.aspx" "Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/23.0.1271.64+Safari/537.11"
```

Lines

```
101.2.186.21        2012-11-27  00:00:01    GET /online/2/2/22002.aspx  200     https://www.exsample.com/online/2/2/22001.aspx  Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/23.0.1271.64+Safari/537.11
```

Comment: Your `line` probably contains a newline (`\n`) at the end that you haven't stripped off. Hence it is included as one of the characters that you `join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lines, when split, couldn't possibly have an index going up to 9 (well they don't for me). But anyways, it looks like your lines are separated by a new line (`'\n'`) and so when you're accessing the last element in the list, you're also accessing the new line.

You can do:

```
agent = '"'+(line.split('\t')[9]).rstrip('\r\n')+'"'
```

Also, your last line doesn't need all that concatenation. You can simplify it to:

```
fo.write(ip + ' - - ' + time + ' ' + method + ' ' + status + ' 0 ' + referrer + ' ' + agent)
```

Or even:

```
fo.write("{0} - - {1} {2} {3} {4} 0 {5} {6}".format(ip, time, method, status, referrer, agent)
```

Comment: It says "I want to put double quotes("") for the beginning and end", so that means the double quotes should be part of the string.

Comment: @Haidro : I tried this......agent = (line.split('\t')[9]) It just print the string without quotes?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage What is `line`? Could you perhaps add an example

Comment: @Haidro : I have added lines to the question since it is clear?

Comment: @Haidro : One more thing,I have done some formatting to the date time etc. Please ignore them :)

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage Edited my answer. I hope that helps!

Comment: @Haidro : With this one it still print the same output? agent = '"'+(line.split('\t')[9]).rstrip('\n')+'"'

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage if you do `print(repr(line.split('\t')[9]))`, what do you get?

Comment: @Haidro: 'Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0)\r\n'

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage Ahh, my latest edit should work now. If it doesn't, then I'm lost

Comment: @Haidro : Finally it worked :) Ur line just print everything in one line..So I added a '\n' to the fo.write line..Anyway Thanks million times..:)

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question directly, but have you considered using Python string formatting?  Either the `%` or the new `.format` way would make your format easier to read and modify.

It would be something like

```
"%s - %s %s %s %s" % (ip, time, method, status, agent)
```